# custom username/password in ssl webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, basichttpbinding

I have a basichttpbinding WCF service that was running using the transport security mode. This works fine however I would like to authenticate the user that requests this service therefore tried to use security mode of TransportWithMessagCredential and message clientCredentialType of UserName and added a service behaviour to call the custom password validator. My issue is when i try to use visual studio to call the reference I get an error saying the service could not be found. Please find my code below and suggest any changes that I may need to make to get this working and prompt me with a username/password when trying to add the service.

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
    propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="WcfTraces.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
        name="traceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="c:\users\**\web_messages.svclog"
    type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=***"
    name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<system.serviceModel>
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
    logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicBindingConfig">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="nameSpaceX.Service">
    <endpoint address="https://************:443/***.svc/"
      binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicBindingConfig"
      contract="nameSpaceY.IService">
      <identity>
        <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="****************" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"
        httpsGetUrl="https://*****:443/***.svc" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
          customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="namespaceX.UserNameValidator, namespaceX" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

**userNameValidator.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IdentityModel.Selectors;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace namespaceX
{
class UserNameValidator: UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string username, string password)
    {
        if(username == "test" && password == "1234")
            return;
        throw new SecurityTokenException("Incorrect username or Password");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "i try to use visual studio to call the reference" - can you clarify what exactly you do and error message detail?

Comment: Basically when I try to browse to the service in my browser I get: Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. This happens when all I changed in the service is to use TransportwithMessageCredential and the service behaviours as described above. When using only transport security it works fine. However, I need to secure it with a username/password.

Comment: Do you try HTTPS://...*.svc when see 404? It is really strange. Security should not move your endpoint.

Comment: Yes. Does my configuration file and the way I refer to userNameValidator look right? Perhaps I need to make some changes.

Comment: I see one issue. See my answer. Is website and APPpool started in IIS? You may see 404 when your site is stopped than IIS will try to use default web site.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need path to *.svc here. Usually `httpsGetUrl` attribute is skipped or stores ...?wsdl

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"
  httpsGetUrl="https://*****:443/***.svc" />
```

That was told with assumption that URL here is the same as one in service endpoint. Ti should be different urls because one is implementation and second one is metadata.

Comment: this is necessary, otherwise WCF points to machine name instead of domain name when the service is created

Comment: dsicovered my mistake. When I browsed to https://*****:443/***.svc i would add an extra slash in the end as follows https://*****:443/***.svc/ and it broke it. Really stupid. Thanks for your help anyway